# Order of centroids across two independent random variables

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

Say I have a function $q_{D, \Theta}: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ that depends on independent random variables $D$ and $\Theta$.
I want to consider "centroids" of $q$ with respect to another function $\ell : \mathcal{Y} \times \mathcal{Y} \to \mathbb{R}_{+}$ with $\ell(a,b)=0$ if and only if $a=b$.
$$
q^\star_{\Theta} := \arg\min_{z} \mathbb{E}_{D}\left[ \ell (z, q_{D, \Theta}) \right] 
$$
$$
\bar{q}_{D} := \arg\min_{z'} \mathbb{E}_{\Theta}\left[ \ell(z', q_{D,\Theta}) \right] 
$$
One can see that for some $\Theta_{1}, \Theta_{2}$ that are distributed as $\Theta$, $q_{\Theta_{1}}^\star = q_{\Theta_{2}}^\star$ (since the $\star$ centroid does not consider $\Theta$).

I now want to prove that, using only these general definitions,
$$
\bar{q}_{D}^\star = q_{\Theta}^\star
$$
or, fully expanded:
$$
\arg \min_{z} \mathbb{E}_{D}\left[ \ell(z, \arg\min_{z'} \mathbb{E}_{\Theta}\left[ z', q_{D, \Theta} \right] ) \right] 
=
\arg\min_{z'} \mathbb{E}_{\Theta}\left[ \ell(z', \arg\min_{z} \mathbb{E}_{D}\left[ \ell(z, q_{D,\Theta}) \right] ) \right] 
$$
This can be shown for the special case of functions $\ell$ where the centroids are just the expectations, i.e. $\arg \min_{z}\mathbb{E}\left[ \ell(z, q) \right] = \mathbb{E}_{}\left[ q \right]$.
However, I think this is also true for this general case. Intuitively, what enables this is that $D$ and $\Theta$ are independent. It would be like taking a mean across one dimension and then another dimension.